# Does ARCore on Android support realtime reflections like ARKit?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arcore, sceneform

I had recently started working on a demo AR (Augmented Reality) project using Sceneform SDK for Android. I had observed that the ARKit supports realtime reflection of the objects in the environment, but I could not find a proper answer on whether the same feature is supported in ARCore. Hence, I wanted to know if there is any way to provide realtime reflections using Sceneform SDK on Android.

Expected Result - The model rendered in the environment should reflect the surrounding objects.

Actual Result - The model currently reflects a static room (default) rather than the actual environment, which is not immersive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's gonna be part of ARCore 2.0 called Environmental HDR : https://developers.googleblog.com/2019/05/ARCore-IO19.html?m=1